# How can I feed data files of different sizes to a CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, input-layer

I have 5022 data files. I want to feed them into a CNN model.

However, the lengths of data files vary from, say, 50 to 1015 rows (the number of columns is constant).

In the case of image files, we can resize or downsample. However, the files I am working with are not image files.

What options do I have to feed those data files into CNN without losing any information?

I am thinking about padding the smaller files with zero.

Would that be a good idea?

Crossposted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630163/how-can-i-feed-data-files-of-different-sizes-to-a-cnn